# Authenticated user not persisting when making ajax calls on Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am working on a project using symphony 2.8.  I currently hitting a wall because the currently authenticated user isn't persisted when I am making an ajax call.  So, I've created a very simple ajax call to test:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ path('user_typeahead') }},
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { term: $term },
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(data) {

    }
});
```

and the controller which goes:

```
public function typeaheadAction(Request $request)
    {
      $user = $this->getUser();
      if ($user->hasRole('ROLE_TOP_ADMIN')) {
        return true;
      }

      return $this->ajaxResponse(array('term' => $request->request->get('term'));
    }
```

and I get this error: `Call to a member function hasRole() on string`

and dumping the $user shows 'anon' which means there is no authenticated user.

Comment: What is your user provider? It looks like it might be broken, check your security.yml

Comment: provider is entity.  there is no issue with the provider as it works in any other request but the ajax.  Probably an environment issue so I added app_dev.php before the path but still getting same result.

Comment: it's in my question.  $user is no longer an instance of User but 'anon'

Comment: It seems that Symfony is unable to associate your ajax request with the authenticated user's session. Compare request headers using browser's dev tools, make sure that domain you are running ajax from is the same domain symfony uses.

Comment: Another thing to try - authnticate using app_dev.php explicitly, then specify the same env in your ajax url

Comment: You need to check that the URL of your typeaheadAction is under a firewall.